# Find the range of: $f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{x^2+1}{2x−1}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{x^2+1}{2x−1} \iff y=\displaystyle\frac{x^2+1}{2x−1}$ We are asked to find the domain and range of the given rational function.

**Domain:**

$\left\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid 2\cdot x−1 \neq 0\right\} \implies \left\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \neq \displaystyle\frac1 2 \right\}$
So the domain for this function is: $D= \mathbb{R} − \left\{\displaystyle\frac 12\right\}$

**Range:**
When it comes to the range of this function this is my work:
\begin{align*}
y & = \frac{x^2 + 1}{2x - 1} \Rightarrow\\
(2x - 1)y & = x^2 + 1 \Rightarrow\\
2xy - y & = x^2 + 1
\end{align*}

---

I don't know how to continue from this point. Is there any trick that I am missing so i can continue? Any methodology that i should follow? Any help would be useful.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I found domain and range ! What have you tried ?

Comment: I've found domain but I can't seem to get range I always get stuck.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your work.  We cannot figure out what mistakes you are making without seeing your work.

Comment: There's no possible way that $\mathcal{D}_{f} = \mathbb{R} - \left\{ 12 \right\}$. It's basic algebra.

\begin{align}
2x-1 \neq 0 &\implies 2x \neq 1\\
&\implies x \neq \dfrac{1}{2}
\end{align}

so domain is $\mathbb{R} - \left\{ \dfrac{1}{2}\right\}$

Comment: Yeah sorry just encoded wrong

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  I restored your previous work so that users will not close your question for not showing work.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your domain is correct.

What you have shown thus far is that $y$ is in the range of the function if and only if there is a real number $x$ in the domain that satisfies the quadratic equation
$$2xy - y = x^2 + 1$$
which we can rewrite as
$$x^2 - 2yx + y + 1 = 0$$
A quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0, a \neq 0$ has real roots if and only if its discriminant $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac \geq 0$.
\begin{align*}
b^2 - 4ac & \geq 0\\
(-2y)^2 - 4(1)(y + 1) & \geq 0\\
4y^2 - 4y - 4 & \geq 0\\
4y^2 - 4y & \geq 4\\
4y^2 - 4y + 1 & \geq 5\\
(2y - 1)^2 & \geq 5\\
|2y - 1| & \geq \sqrt{5}
\end{align*}
Hence, $2y - 1 \geq \sqrt{5}$ or $2y - 1 \leq -\sqrt{5}$.

\begin{align*}
2y - 1 & \geq \sqrt{5} & 2y - 1 & \leq -\sqrt{5}\\
2y & \geq 1 + \sqrt{5} & 2y & \leq 1 - \sqrt{5}\\
y & \geq \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} & y & \leq \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{align*}
Hence, the range of the function is
$$\left(-\infty, \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\right] \cup \left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}, \infty\right)$$

Comment: +1, Concise, clear and linked it to the domain :)

Comment: Damn you got me faster. 

Glad to see we both got the same.

Comment: What happens if my discriminant is <0? What does that do to the range?

Comment: A real number $y$ is in the range if and only if there exists a real number $x$ in the domain such that $f(x) = y$.  We showed that the equation $f(x) = y$ was equivalent to the quadratic equation $x^2 - 2yx + y + 1 = 0$.   Hence, $y$ is in the range if and only if there exists a real number $x$ in the domain that satisfies that equation.  For that to be true, the discriminant of that quadratic equation must be nonnegative.  If the discriminant were negative, then the quadratic equation would have complex roots, so $y$ would not be in the range of the function.

Answer (score 2):

Let's solve this completely.

**Domain**: The denominator must no be zero. As such
\begin{align}
2x-1 \neq 0 &\implies 2x \neq 1\\
&\implies x\neq \dfrac{1}{2}.
\end{align}
So $\mathcal{D}_f = \mathbb{R} - \left\{ \dfrac{1}{2} \right\}$.

**Range**: Starting from
\begin{align}
2xy-y=x^2 + 1 &\implies x^2 + (-2y)x + (y+1) = 0
\end{align}
which is a quadratic form that has discriminant
\begin{align}
\Delta = b^2 - 4ac &= 4y^2-4(y+1)\\
&=4(y^2-y-1)
\end{align}
and we must ask for $\Delta \geq 0$ if the function has to have a range. Solving
\begin{align}
y^2-y-1 = 0 \implies \ldots\implies y_1 = \dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}, y_2=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{align}
and thus the above will be positive if and only if
\begin{align}
y \in (-\infty, \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}] \cup [\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}, \infty) \implies f(x) \in (-\infty, \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}] \cup [\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}, \infty)
\end{align}
which is the range.

Answer (score 0):

**Range of the function:**

> $2xy-y=x^2+1\iff y^2-y-1=x^2-2xy+y^2\iff\\ y^2-y-1=(x+y)^2\\
> \text{Since it is always true that: }(x+y)^2\ge0\text{ so and } y^2-y-1\ge0\ \\
> \text{From the quatric formula we have: }\Delta=b^2-4ac =(-1)^2+4=5 $
> $$\displaystyle  y_{1,2}=\frac {1\pm \sqrt{5}}2$$
> $\text{We know that in the range: }Y=\left[\displaystyle\frac {1-\sqrt{5}}{2},\displaystyle\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right], y^2-y-1\le0 $
> $\text{Hence, the range of the function we are looking is: } M=\left(-\infty, \displaystyle\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\right] \cup \left[\displaystyle\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}, \infty \right)$

---

Of course there is α methodology but you need to know meanings  like: $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)$$
$\text{ which are more advanced}$

Comment: I do not think it necessary. It's almost always the case that students when learning about quadratic equations' field of solutions they just take it for granted that whenever the solution goes "too far back" it's the infinity symbol with a parenthesis in the domain.

At least that's how I was taught it.

Comment: What do you mean by the phrase "too far back"?

Comment: It's the way teachers usually patch up the need to take the $\lim_{x \to -\infty}$ of a quadratic function.

Comment: I don't understand completely what do you mean .But what i  was referring is this:It is proven that if a function is increasing(which means that:$\forall x_1,x_2 \epsilon D \text{ and } x_1<x_2 \rightarrow f(x_1)<f(x_2))$ $\text{ then }$ $R=\left[\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x),\displaystyle\lim_{x \to b}f(x)\right] \text{ with (a,b) =D , and of course D is the domain and R is the Range.}$
$\text{Similar process if the  function is dicreasing.}$